# FFLIB / SOC / Fowler Domain question

Tags: apex, fflib

There's probably 100000 answers to this, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the domain layer is supposed to handle more advanced trigger logic.

For instance, what if a subscription cancellation (think a scenario like: subsctiption__c where status is changed to "Cancelled") is picked up through my onAfterUpdate method, but it now needs to perform more complex app logic like notifications.. other dml etc... Should I be calling the service layer from the domain?

And if so, where should I perform the DML?  I thought all DML should be in the service layer, but wouldn't that mean all after triggers performing DML need to call service methods?

Thanks!